# Tkinter Radiobuttons not working properly in Toplevel window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button, toplevel

I'm building a GUI with Tkinter in Python and I'm having trouble with radio buttons. I have two radio buttons in a LabelFrame widget and I'm using a StringVar to track the selected value. However, when I run the program, both radio buttons are initially unselected, but after a few seconds both become selected. Additionally, changes to the selected value are not always reflected in the GUI.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MenuSettings:
    def __init__(self, parent, settings):
        
        window = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        window.title("settings")

        database_frame = tk.LabelFrame(
            window, text="choose drive: ", font=("Arial", 12))
        database_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=10)

        database_var = tk.StringVar(value=settings.db_path)

        database_radio_g = tk.Radiobutton(
            database_frame, text="G:", value="PATH_G", variable=database_var, 
            font=("Arial", 12))
        database_radio_g.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        database_radio_server = tk.Radiobutton(
            database_frame, text="Server", value="PATH_SERVER", variable=database_var, 
            font=("Arial", 12))
        database_radio_server.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # following code is necessary
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #def on_database_var_changed(*args):
        #    print('database_var changed:', database_var.get())

        #database_var.trace('w', on_database_var_changed)       


from wotan.CLS import cls

settings = cls.Settings.getInstance()

class Application(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("Application")
        self.configure(background='black')

        self._show_menu_settings()


    def _show_menu_settings(self):
        settings_window=MenuSettings(self, settings)



def main():
  app = Application()
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`settings` is a singleton class to read some variables from a locally stored textfile.
Trace statement incl. function is commented out in class `MenuSettings`

I've tried several things, such as setting the value option for the radio buttons, removing other parts of my code to isolate the issue, use window.update() and window.update_idletasks(), but nothing seems to work.

The only solution I found is to add a trace with a function to print the StringVar, which is not an ideal solution for an App.
Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried saving a reference to the variables? As written, they are just local variables, subject to being deleted once `__init__` returns.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I have tried to work with instance variables and class variables with no effect on the bahaviour of the Radiobuttons.

Comment: Also, please try to make an example we can run. If you could remove the dependency on `wotan`, that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use instance variable on `database_var` (in `MenuSettings`) and `settings_window` (in `Application`) to avoid garbage collection:

```py
class MenuSettings:
    def __init__(self, parent, settings):
        ...
        # use instance variable
        self.database_var = tk.StringVar(value=settings.db_path)

        database_radio_g = tk.Radiobutton(
            database_frame, text="G:", value="PATH_G", variable=self.database_var,
            font=("Arial", 12))
        database_radio_g.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        database_radio_server = tk.Radiobutton(
            database_frame, text="Server", value="PATH_SERVER", variable=self.database_var,
            font=("Arial", 12))
        database_radio_server.pack(side="left", padx=10)

...

class Application(tk.Tk):
    ...

    def _show_menu_settings(self):
        # use instance variable
        self.settings_window = MenuSettings(self, settings)
...
```

I would suggest that `MenuSettings` inherits form `tk.Toplevel` instead, then you don't need to use instance variable on `settings_window`.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I have found also another solution: define 'database_var' as a global variable. However, yours is the best!